# DynamicLink deeplink url is nil when navigate user to appStore and first download

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

I tried to create dynamicLink at Firebase console to navigate user to download my app at appStore,
and when they launch app for the first time I keep getting DynamicLink object with nil url.

```
 func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

      if let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
            //  dynamicLink url is nil 
      }
}
```

```
<FIRDynamicLink: 0x281ad2a40, url [(null)], match type: none, minimumAppVersion: N/A, match message: (null)>
```

and the url is

```
MyAppSchema://google/link/?dismiss=1&is_weak_match=1
```

when I perform diagnostic i got this

```
---- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output start ----
Firebase Dynamic Links framework version 3.0.1
System information: OS iOS, OS version 12.1.4, model iPhone
Current date 2019-03-28 10:10:21 +0000
Device locale en-US (raw en_US), timezone Asia/Taipei
    Specified custom URL scheme is {MyAppSchema} and Info.plist contains such scheme in CFBundleURLTypes key.
    AppID Prefix: {AppID Prefix}, Team ID: {teamID}, AppId Prefix equal to Team ID: YES
performDiagnostic completed successfully! No errors found.
---- Firebase Dynamic Links diagnostic output end ----
```

has tried / confirmed :

1. not using safari private mode
2. short link / long link
3. app not installed
4. switch preferredLanguages / region / locale
5. preview page enabled
6. wifi and Cellular

I opened an issue at Firebase iOS SDK repo

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2666

Steps to reproduce:

1. app not installed
2. click on a dynamicLink
3. preview page
4. appStore page
5. build to device from Xcode
6. get DynamicLink object but url is nil

expect step 6 to get url

Comment: Stuck at the same issue. Can anybody please help?

Comment: Did you get any solution?? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

So I have been struggling for quite a while now, and also in the current situation you are in, all the steps have been followed similar to the documentation and debug shows it as having no errors.

I finally figured it out  tonight, or should I say 14 mins into the new year 2020!  All I needed was to enable dynamic links in the google api console. Why was this not documented at all.

Heres the link!
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/overview

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try this:

Missing `FirebaseDynamicLinkCustomDomains` causing this problem, you should update this to your ios project:
For example, if your url is:
`targetEncodedLink = https://yourtargetlink.com` (you should encode it to this `https%3A%2F%2Fyourtargetlink.com`)

`dynamicLink = https://yourfirebasedynamiclink.com/link/?link=${encodedLink}&apn=com.example&isi=1449448875&ibi=com.example`

You should add this key to your ios project

```
// Info.plist
<dict////>
  <key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
  <array>
    <string>https://yourtargetlink.com</string>
    <string>https://yourfirebasedynamiclink.com/link</string>
  </array>
</dict>
```

From this instruction:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains

Answer (score 0):

Try to update Firebase/DynamicLinks.
I'd had the same issue and run pod update Firebase/DynamicLinks.
Now Firebase/DynamicLinks is 6.21.0 and DynamicLink object has url value.

Answer (score 0):

pod update Firebase if you're on iOS 13